# Making an image responsive

Tags: asp.net, image, mapping

i build a header in photoshop and imported it to visual basic 2010. I want the header to be a bit more dynamic, so when i press on part of the image (that says contacts for example), it will transfer me to another page.

i know that there is a function in css that does this, it is called mapping. Dreamweaver has an easy way of doing it. But is it possible to map an area on the image, which would make the image respond (as if he clicked a button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area mapping links leads to horrible and unnecessary markup. Just put an anchor link around your **entire** header image like so:

```
<a href="~/default.aspx" title="Home" runat="server">
    <img src="~/images/header.jpg" alt=Home" style="border:none;" 
        runat="server" />
</a>
```

If you want to go with Image Maps (not a good design), check these links:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp

http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: so i can use an anchor link, around parts of the image or is it not possible?

Comment: No that is not possible. If you want to link around parts of the image then you have mapped coordinates - I recommend against this type of design but will update my answer if you choose to go that route :-)

Comment: i think what i will do, i will slice the image in photoshop so that i have a few images ..then a click on one image will transfer the user to a different page

Answer (score 2):

ASP.net provides 3 ways to give imagemap, these are called 'Hotspot' properties of imagemap control. Circular and rectangular hotspots are easy to understand. here is an example..

```
   <asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server">
            <asp:CircleHotSpot NavigateUrl="nextPage.aspx" />
            <asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom="50" Left="50" NavigateUrl="contactpage.aspx" 
                Right="10" Top="10" />
        </asp:ImageMap>
```

Sample image illustrated here
[image]

ASP setting screenshot
[image]